# Can't run Add-Migration on asp.net core Identity + PostgreSQL when change user id type

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, identity

I made a project with **asp.net core 5** and **Identity** and **PostgreSql** for database,
when i change user id to `int`, then can't run `Add-Migration` and show this error below but when use **SqlServer** haven't any error and run correctly.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design.Internal.NpgsqlAnnotationCodeGenerator.GenerateValueGenerationStrategy(IDictionary`2 annotations, Boolean onModel)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design.Internal.NpgsqlAnnotationCodeGenerator.GenerateFluentApiCalls(IProperty property, IDictionary`2 annotations)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpSnapshotGenerator.GeneratePropertyAnnotations(IProperty property, IndentedStringBuilder stringBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpSnapshotGenerator.GenerateProperty(String builderName, IProperty property, IndentedStringBuilder stringBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpSnapshotGenerator.GenerateProperties(String builderName, IEnumerable`1 properties, IndentedStringBuilder stringBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpSnapshotGenerator.GenerateEntityType(String builderName, IEntityType entityType, IndentedStringBuilder stringBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpSnapshotGenerator.GenerateEntityTypes(String builderName, IReadOnlyList`1 entityTypes, IndentedStringBuilder stringBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationsGenerator.GenerateMetadata(String migrationNamespace, Type contextType, String migrationName, String migrationId, IModel targetModel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
```

My code changes for change user id to `int` is:

in `Startup`:

```
services.AddIdentity<MyIdentityUser, IdentityRole<int>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyAppContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

in `data context`:

```
public class MyAppContext : IdentityDbContext<MyIdentityUser, IdentityRole<int>, int>
...

public class MyIdentityUser:IdentityUser<int>
    {}
```

What is the problem?

I want make this change for improve Database performance in queries because I think  query for integer is faster than default user id which is `Guid`(which is long string instead integer), is this correct?

Comment: Hi @MohsenB,Did you delete all migration files and drop the database?

Comment: @Yinqiu Yes, even tested in new simple project.